# unwanted blank spaces in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm facing problem with unwanted blank spaces between two text boxes in my SSRS report. first testbox contains sub header(left-aligned), "Summary". second text box contains comments. maximum limit is 10000 characters.
When I googeld, I found the below calcualtions to consider. I corrected the values to satisfy the conditions. Still I'm facing problem. Please suggest me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Note: text length in comments textbox is 5200charcters.

```
Page.Height >= Page.TopMargin 
         + ReportHeader.Height (no header)
         + ReportBody.Height 
         + ReportFooter.Height (no footer)
         + Page.BottomMargin
```

My page values
24>=1 + 20.57513 + 1

```
Page.Width  >= Page.LeftMargin + ReportBody.Width + Page.RightMargin
```

My page values
15 >= 0.5 + 12.76427 + 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by Changing the property of textbox. Property:"KeepTogether", Value:False.
It shown the paragraphs in pdf file as desired without any blank area.